# Hiding menu on mobile only when viewing posts?

Tags: posts, menus, mobile

I would like to hide menu on mobile only when viewing posts.
Menu at the homepage should be visible on mobile but not the other pages. How can I do it?

Here is the menu snippet:

```
<nav class="navigation cf" <?php echo implode(' ', $nav_data); ?>>

            <div class="mobile" data-type="<?php echo Bunyad::options()->mobile_menu_type; ?>" data-search="<?php echo Bunyad::options()->mobile_nav_search; ?>">
                <a href="#" class="selected">
                    <span class="text"><?php _e('Navigate', 'bunyad'); ?></span><span class="current"></span> <i class="hamburger fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'walker' =>  'Bunyad_Menu_Walker')); ?>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are editing a child theme (or somehow protecting your changes from future update/over-writing) a very simple way to accomplish this is with a CSS rule that targets your mobile menu, then applies `display: none` to it.

Using a combination of media queries and carefully written CSS selectors, you can target exactly the HTML elements you wish to hide, and in what context.

My guess is you will need a combination of body class (for the correct content type), media query and appropriate CSS.

Comment: There should be a PHP solution, CSS won't handle it alone if I want to hide it only from posts and not from homepage...

Comment: I disagree.  Your theme likely has plenty of classes available specific to the areas and elements you wish to hide.  There is a PHP solution as well.  The simplest route is likely with the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) available in WP.

Comment: You are right, I thought about what you said and tried to do it. Ta da! it worked, thanks man!

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work. Which solution did you go with?  Might be useful for those that come after to post a few details.

Comment: Solution:
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 799px){
.single-post .navigation {display: none;} }